# badge awarded, but I already had it for almost three years

Tags: bug

Today I was notified that I was awarded the gold badge for the tag **microsoft-excel**

[image]

Only two others have that gold tag badge, and they both earned it in 2019.

[image]

The thing is, I already earned exactly that badge in May 2018 and at that time I was the only one in SuperUser.com who had a gold tag badge for **microsoft-excel**. I was so excited about it that I took a screenshot and posted it on facebook. That's why I still have a copy of the screenshot.

[image]

So, my question is: What happened to my first gold tag badge??? Why is it no longer showing??

**Edit:** I see the explanation from Taryn about the bug, but I don't consider this "fixed". So I'm changing my question to:

-- Can the real award date be restored, please?

I find it quite noteworthy that I've had that badge for almost three years. This tech world is very male dominated and it's rare that a woman gets to be in first place here, so let's please not bury that achievement because of a software bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a [network wide bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973/295232) with tag scores and associated badges. It was fixed yesterday, Stack Exchange developer @Taryn wrote [quite a lengthy explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360040/295232) about it.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the award date of the badge should not be yesterday.

Comment: That is true; I'm not sure if they can fix that. They keep track of when votes are cast, so they can construct historical post scores, tag scores and hence tag badges, but it'll be complicated...

Comment: I left a comment in the discussion you linked to. I'm sure if Taryn can fix it, it will be dealt with.